# How to redirect a user to my application using App Url

Tags: android

I want my users to be redirected to a particular screen of my app when they clicked on an app URL which I sent through the message to them.

Comment: have you sued search before asking?

Answer (score 0):

For that, you need to use deep linking. Please take a look of the document provided by the Google developer site.

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking